# what are the steps to be performed for Replication of AWS RDS Postgresql into On-Premise Postgresql using AWS DMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration, aws-dms, disaster-recovery

I have a requirement of replicating data from AWS RDS Postgres(12) Database to On-Premise Postgres(12) Database for disaster recovery purpose. I have found stuff about replication from On-premise to AWS RDS. But How can we implement it for AWS RDS to On-premise?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I think you have two options here:

1. Use AWS Database Migration Service, setup source endpoint = pgsql on RDS, and target endpoint = pgsql on-premises, and setup DMS task for full load and CDC, detail you can refer to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.PostgreSQL.html
2. Setup replication from RDS pgsql to on-premises pgsql using pgsql native logical replication, there is a very good AWS blog talking exactly this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-logical-replication-to-replicate-managed-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-and-amazon-aurora-to-self-managed-postgresql/

Comment: i would prefer option 2, native solution is always better :)